# String replace on a very large file

Tags: regex, bash, vim, sed

I have a giant text file that is JSON. You can see it here: http://api.mtgdb.info/cards/. I have saved this JSON to a file called `cards.json`.

In `cards.json`, I need to escape every single quote `'` with a backslash `\`.

So I need to replace `'` with `\'`.

Usually this is trivial in any editor, however the file is too large. **How can I escape all single quotes in this string?**

**What I've tried:**

1. I tried using `sed`. My command was `sed s/\'/\\\'/ cards.json > cards_cleaned.json`. However the cards_cleaned.json file did not have any escaped `'`, it was just an exact copy of `cards.json`. Sed works when i do `sed s/\'/foobar/ cards.json > cards_cleaned.json`, so I'm assuming something is wrong with my escaping backslashes.
2. I tried using `vim`. I opened cards.json in vim `$ vi cards.json`. Then I tried a global string replace using `:%s/'/\'/g`. This did not change anything in the file.

Comment: Why do you need one backslash? As you see in jm666 post, this gives invalid json code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @anubhava's or @gboffi's answers **works**, they produces and **INVALID** JSON.

[JSON allows only](http://json.org) few characters after the `backslash`:

```
\"
\\
\/
\b
\f
\n
\r
\t
\u four-hex-digits
```

e.g. the part of the following original (correct) JSON

```
[
   {
      "description" : "Whenever a land enters the battlefield, Ankh of Mishra deals 2 damage to that land's controller.",
      "rarity" : "Rare",
      "name" : "Ankh of Mishra"
   }
]
```

you want to get

```
[
   {
      "description" : "Whenever a land enters the battlefield, Ankh of Mishra deals 2 damage to that land\'s controller.",
      "rarity" : "Rare",
      "name" : "Ankh of Mishra"
   }
]
#e.g. instead of the land's want land\'s
```

But this is an INVALID JSON.

So, if you (for some strange reason) want have the `backslash`, you need to use double `\\`, such:

```
[
   {
      "description" : "Whenever a land enters the battlefield, Ankh of Mishra deals 2 damage to that land\\'s controller.",
      "rarity" : "Rare",
      "name" : "Ankh of Mishra"
   }
]
```

### Solution (for both)

with `perl`

```
perl -pE "s/'/\\\'/g" < mtg_cards.json > cards.malformed.json
#changes "land's" to wrong "land\'s"
```

and

```
perl -pE "s/'/\\\\'/g" < mtg_cards.json > card_with_double_BS.json
#changes "land's" to "land\\s"
```

*Ps: Because your file is only one long (30MB) line, the `vim` has some problems. You can **pretty print** (fold and indent) the JSON, before editing. Many tools here, i'm using the `json_xs` command from the [JSON_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) perl package. After "prettyfying" you can use the `vim` safely.*

Comment: But what if OP pars this trough another program that gives problems with the single quote and an escape helps since its removed in the process and preserve the single quote?

Comment: @Jotne - speculations. Anyway, (as you can see) I included a solution for both.

Comment: Yes its pure speculation.  It was just a comment to the invalid Json. As long as OP does not comment on what is working and not, we have to wait and see.  I may be a reason to why OP ask for one slash and not two.

Comment: @jm666 your remark is wise but as jotne present, you cannot yourself speculate on destination of file. (+1 for both of you)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu and THEREFORE i included a solution for **both** scenario in my original answer, now edited it as bold (for sure). :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes in the shell to avoid quoting the single quote character, but the you have to be careful because the shell, for a double quoted string, use the backslash as a quoting character

```
$ echo "eoieriou'iouou'oiuiouiuo"|sed "s/'/\\'/g"
eoieriou'iouou'oiuiouiuo
```

and the command that `sed` is trying to execute is `s/'/\'/g` but `sed` quoting character is the backslash, so that you substitute each single quote with a single quote...

We have to quote the backslash *also* when it arrives to `sed`, so let's try

```
$ echo "eoieriou'iouou'oiuiouiuo"|sed "s/'/\\\\'/g"  # Four (4) backslashes in a row
eoieriou\'iouou\'oiuiouiuo
$
```

That's OK, isn't it? because `sed` is instructed to do `s/'/\\'/g` so that the quoted character, from the POV of `sed`, is the backslash itself...

Please note that the quotes, single or double, are not special characters from the POV of `sed`, they're special only in the context of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

In Vi you will need to escape the \ character.

Try using

```
:%s/'/\\'/g
```

For me it worked.

> Test.txt
>
> \'\'\' \'\'\'

Comment: This works on a test, but vim doesn't to ever finish the operation.

Comment: You can then use a different delimiter with sed:  cat cards.json | sed "s_'_/'_g" > cards.json.clean

Answer (score 1):

You need to double escape the backelas, so use:

```
sed -i.bak "s/'/\\\\'/g" cards.json
```

Comment: It works with three "\" too: `sed -i.bak "s/'/\\\'/g" cards.json`

Comment: @Jotne Yes it works, but I'm having a hard time explaining to me why it works..., I wonder if you'd care to explain why it works in a separate answer

Comment: @gboffi I do not know why, just tested it. No errors, and correct output.

Comment: @Jotne It seems that the sequence `\'` is interpreted differently by the shell when it is double quoted, like in `$ echo \' "\'"` that produces the following output: `' \'` --- still I have to find the _real_ explanation... another day maybe, ciao

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this, in vim.

```
 :%s/'/\\\'/g
```

In sed,

```
 sed "s/'/\\\'/g" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
cat file
hi'more data here'
```

```
awk '{gsub(g,"\\"g)}1' g="'" file
hi\'more data here\'
```

Or if you need double backslash:

```
awk '{gsub(g,"\\\\"g)}1' g="'" file
hi\\'more data here\\'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed "s/'/\\\\&/g" cards.json > cards_cleaned.json
```

- no need of your first escaped in search pattern `\'`
- you should surround by double quote (single if single quote was not the char to change) and escape the escape due to double quote used at shell level in this case

Comment: Your answer is corresponding to the  _non working_ example in mine, so I guess it may suffer the same problem that I have demonstrated...

Comment: `$ echo "eoieriou'iouou'oiuiouiuo" | sed "s/'/\\&'/g"` gives back `eoieriou&iouou&oiuiouiuo`, because the `sed` command that is executed is `s/'/\&/g` (please note that I'm not downvoting, but you could test your answers before posting, couldn't you?)

Comment: @gboffi event if you have'nt down vote, your reply worth it (i upvote your comment for this). I adapt with the double double escape i try to avoid using `&`